# Compare two digit numbers for a lottery program how to random?

Tags: java

I want to compare 2 digit numbers for a lottery program

and the 2 digits are random

so I write this code:

```
package home6;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lottery {

    public static void main(String[] arga) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your lottery pick (two digits): ");
        int guess = input.nextInt();

        int guessDigit1 = guess / 10;
        int guessDigit2 = guess % 10;

        int lottery = (int) Math.random();
        System.out.println("The lottery number is " + lottery);

        int lotteryDigit1 = lottery / 10;
        int lotteryDigit2 = lottery % 10;

        if (guess == lottery) {
            System.out.println("Match all digits: you win $10,000");
        } else if (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1 && guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2) {
            System.out.println("Match all digits: you win $3,000");
        } else if (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1 || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2 || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1 || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2) {
            System.out.println("Match one digit: you win $1,000");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, no match");

        }
    }
}
```

In line 17, `// int lottery = (int) Math.random();`,  what's the problem?

how to random lottery?

[image]

this is my question .

Answer (score 1):

You want a number between 0 and 99:

```
int lottery = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` return the result between 0.0 ~ 1.0. So you cast it to `Integer` that will always be 0. If you want to lottery number be 0 ~ 100, make it `(int) (Math.random()*100)`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is:

```
Random random = new Random();

public void test() {
    int zeroToNinetyNine = random.nextInt(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lottery {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter your two lucky Digits:");
        int think = input.nextInt();
        
        int thinkdigit1 = think / 10;
        int thinkdigit2 = think % 10;
        
        int casino= (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        System.out.println("The lottery number is:" +casino);
        
        
        int casinonumber1= casino / 10;
        int casinonumber2 = casino % 10;
        
        
        if (think==casino)
        {
            System.out.println("Perfact match!. you won $10,000");
        }
        else if (thinkdigit1==casinonumber2 && thinkdigit2==casinonumber1)
        {
            System.out.println("Match Both Digit: you won $3000");
        }
        else if (thinkdigit1==casinonumber1||thinkdigit1==casinonumber2||thinkdigit2==casinonumber1||thinkdigit2==casinonumber2)
        {
            System.out.println("Only One Digit matched: you won $1000");
        }
        else { System.out.println("Sorry!! No match! Better Luck Next Time!! you can't try again!");}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the description to your code. So that it is easy to understand.